# MATLAB - finding max/min in selected rows/columns of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

if i have a matrix, say:

```
A = [ 0 2 4 0 
      2 0 5 0
      4 5 0 3
      0 0 3 0 ]
```

and i want to find the maximum value in the matrix i can type:

```
max(max(A))
```

or

```
max(A(:))
```

if i only want to find the maximum of rows 1 and 2 and columns 3 and 4 i can do this:

```
a = [1 2]
b = [3 4]

max(max(A(a,b))
```

but what if i want to find the indices of the rows and columns that correspond to that value?

according to the matlab documentation, if i am using the whole matrix i can use the ind2sub function:

```
[val,idx] = max(A(:))
[row,col] = ind2sub(size(A),idx)
```

but how can i get that working for my example where i am using vectors `a` and `b` to determine the rows and columns it finds the values over?

here is the only way i have been able to work it out so far:

```
max_val = 0;
max_idx = [1 1];
for ii = a
    [val,idx] = max(A(ii,b))
    if val > max_val
        max_val = val
        max_idx = [ii idx]
```

but that seems rather clunky to me.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the submatrix A(a,b) is contiguous (like in your example):

```
 A = [ 0 2 4 0 
  2 0 5 0
  4 5 0 3
  0 0 3 0 ]

a = [1 2]; b = [3 4];
B = A(a,b)
[val,idx] = max(B(:));
[row,col] = ind2sub(size(B),idx);
maxrow = row + a(1) - 1;
maxcol = col + b(1) - 1;
```

You are finding the relative index in the submatrix B. Which is equivalent to the additional rows and columns from the upper left corner of the submatrix.

Now assuming that a and b result in a set of rows and columns that are NOT a contiguous submatrix, e.g. a = [1 3], b = [3 4], the result is very similar. "row" and "col" are the index in the a and b vectors:

```
A = [ 0 2 4 0 
  2 0 5 0
  4 5 0 3
  0 0 3 0 ]

a = [1 3]; b = [3 4];
B = A(a,b)
[val,idx] = max(B(:));
[row,col] = ind2sub(size(B),idx);
maxrow = a(row);
maxcol = b(col);
```

Now you're working in the index of indexes.

Comment: woudl this work if `a=[1 3]` and `b=[2 4]`? or only if there is no overlap?

Comment: No, that set of rows and columns wouldn't really be a contiguous submatrix, so simply adding in the relative index won't work. Take those numbers to an extreme, like a = [1 100] and b = [2 2000]. that's still only a 2x2 but you are pulling elements from vastly different positions in the matrix.

you need a more general method for that. It wouldn't be too different though. In my code above, "row" and "col" should point to the index in a or b that you should use. I will edit my answer above.